Dual annotations/decorators of Prometheus Client & FastAPI on same function is not working as expected
I have a use case where I need to have two decorator type of annotation for a single function. I have a rest endpoint for which I need to capture the metrics using prometheus client module. I'm trying something like this, but its not working.
rest_app = APIRouter(prefix='/rest')
TIME_METRICS_ANNOTATION = Gauge('request_time_taken', 'Time Taken for My Endpoint')


@TIME_METRICS_ANNOTATION.time()
@rest_app.post("/endpoint")
async def my_endpoint(request: Request):
    # body  

I tried swapping the annotations too, but whichever is immediately above the method definition, only that is taking effect and not the other.
I'm aware that there are some other ways of doing it as follows, but the initial approach with annotations would be cleaner code.
@rest_app.post("/endpoint")
async def my_endpoint(request: Request):
    start_time = time.process_time()
    # body
    TIME_METRICS_ANNOTATION.set(time.process_time() - start_time)

or
@rest_app.post("/endpoint")
async def my_endpoint(request: Request):
    my_endpoint_body(request)
    
@TIME_METRICS_ANNOTATION.time()
def my_endpoint_body(request: Request):
    # body

Any help is appreciated.
Side Note Query : Is there a built-in decorator for Counter type? I'm facing issues as Counter.inc() is not a callable unlike Gauge.time() or Summary.time()

Any reason you can't use prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator? It should provide this out of the box. Otherwise, I would probably implement endpoint timing in a middleware.

Primary reason is prometheus-client (https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) is the official library of Prometheus for python. That apart, prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator doing it out of the box or the middleware approach are both for all APIs, which is kind of redundant in my case.

I had a similar issue recently and I worked around (because I can't say it's a proper way) in the following way (I'm also looking for simpler ways).
PROCESS_COUNT = Counter("example:processing_count", "Number of event", ["event"])
PROCESS_TIME = Gauge("example:processing", "Time spent processing event", ["event"], unit="seconds")

# let's register how much time it take to answer on this endpoint
@PROCESS_TIME.labels("answer_json").time()
async def answer_json(request):
    # let's count how many time this function has been called here
    PROCESS_COUNT.labels("answer_json").inc()
    # let's also register how much time this specific piece of code takes!
    with ClientSession() as session, PROCESS_TIME.labels("example:update").time():
        # ...
    return Response(
        content_type="application/json",
        text=json.dumps(
            # ...
        ),
    )


